# How to remove legend from bottom of chart - amcharts

Tags: jquery, linechart, amcharts

Can you please help me out to remove the legend (of y-axis data) from the below the line-chart. This is the icon that helps to remove the corresponding line from the line-chart.

See inline image[image: To remove the red-bordered section]

Comment: Seeing your actual code would help a lot here, although from looking at the [documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptmaps/AmLegend) it appears you have to add a legend manually for it to appear. Have you tried removing the code which creates the legend?

Comment: @rory Do u have any idea how i can add a class or and id selector to the legend container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In amcharts the legends are added manually, In your case jut remove the lines which add legends to the chart.

For e.g., 
The legends are added as follows,

```
 var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
 chart.addLegend(legend);
```

OR

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
    {
        "legend": {
                    "useGraphSettings": true
                  },
     }
```

Just remove the above lines from your code.

Comment: Do u have any idea how i can add a class or and id selector to the legend container? This is because I need these legends in a chart and not in other. So, I cannot remove them in total.

Comment: Every chart will have its own chart object instance. just don't add the legend objects to chart instance on which you wish to hide them. Hope this works for you. Let me know if you still have some problem.

Comment: Yes! removed the legend for the desired chart, and it worked! thanks Jatin

Answer (score 5):

You can still keep your graphs settings (labels, balloons etc) but hide the legend:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chart", {
    "legend": {
        "enabled": false
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
              "type": "gantt",
             "hideCredits":true
})
```